# Issue with replicate R function : doing Monte-Carlo to estimate variance of a ratio

Tags: r, montecarlo

I try to use `replicate` `R` function to doing Monte Carlo on a ratio (by sampling firstly the numerator and after the denominator and finally estimate the variance of ratio between both).

For this, I did (`nRed=5 and nRow=36`) :

```
y1 <- array(0, dim=c(nRow))
y2 <- array(0, dim=c(nRow,nRed))

y2_sp <- array(0, dim=c(nRow,nRed))
y2_ph <- array(0, dim=c(nRow,nRed))

nSample_var <- 1000
nSample_mc <- 1000
# Declare arrays
y3_1<-array(0, dim=c(nSample_var,nRed));y3_2<-array(0, dim=c(nSample_var,nRed));
y3 <- array(0, dim=c(nSample_var,nRed))
set.seed(123)
for (i in 1:nRed) {
        y3_1[,i] <- y2_sp[,i] * replicate(nSample_mc, rchisq(nSample_var,df=sum(2*y1+1)))
        y3_2[,i] <- y2_ph[,i] * replicate(nSample_mc, rchisq(nSample_var,df=sum(2*y1+1)))
        y3[,i] <- y3_1[,i]/y3_2[,i]
      }
      print(paste0('mean_fid = ', ratio_squared[i]))
      print(paste0('mean_exp = ', mean(y3[,i])))
      print(paste0('numerator : var = ', var(y3_1[,i]), ', sigma = ', sd(y3_1[,i])))
      print(paste0('denominator : var = ', var(y3_2[,i]), ', sigma = ', sd(y3_2[,i])))
      print(paste0('var = ', var(y3[,i]), ', sigma = ', sd(y3[,i])))
      }
```

But I get systematically the error message at execution :

```
[1] "row = 36"
Error in y3_1[, i] <- y2_sp[, i] * replicate(nSample_mc, rchisq(nSample_var,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
In addition: Warning message:
In y2_sp[, i] * replicate(nSample_mc, rchisq(nSample_var, df = sum(2 *  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
Execution halted
```

I can't find how to debug this error.

### Update

Thanks to the comments, I managed to do Monte-Carlo to compute the variance of the ratio of `y3_1[,i]/y3_2[,i]` (for a given column `i-th` of data).

The `replicate` function simply repeats `nSample_mc` times the generation of `nSample_var`random variables following a chi2 distribution that is weighted by y2_sp[,i] and y2_ph[,i] data columns.

Actually, I am looking for the variance of the following numerator (this is the same expression for denominator except the C_l) by Monte-Carlo (so with `replicate` function) :

if `Y_l = Σ_m alm2 => Y_l =d C_l Chisquare(2l+1)`

and so `Σ_l Y_l =d Σ_l C_l Chisquare(2l+1) =d C_l Chisquare(Σ_l (2l+1))`

"`=d`" means equality in distribution sense.

1. But in the last expression, Have I got to consider C_l like a random variable also or just a factor in front of `Chisquare(Σ_l (2l+1))` ?

So, I may have find a workaround by declaring (`nRow=36` in my code):

```
nSample_var <- 100*nRow
nSample_mc <- 1000

# Declare arrays
y3_1<-array(0, dim=c(nSample_var*nSample_mc,nRed));y3_2<-array(0, dim=c(nSample_var*nSample_mc,nRed));
y3 <- array(0, dim=c(nSample_var*nSample_mc,nRed))
```

and doing after :

```
set.seed(123)
for (i in 1:nRed) {
    y3_1[,i] <- y2_sp[,i] * replicate(nSample_mc, rchisq(nSample_var,df=sum(2*y1+1)))
    y3_2[,i] <- y2_ph[,i] * replicate(nSample_mc, rchisq(nSample_var,df=sum(2*y1+1)))
    y3[,i] <- y3_1[,i]/y3_2[,i]
}
```

2. With this method, it seems to produce expected variance on the ration but I think I didn't take into account the sum on `l` in the expression : have I the right to write `=d Σ_l C_l Chisquare(2l+1) =d C_l Chisquare(Σ_l (2l+1))` : what do you think about this problem ? it is difficult to grasp since we are reasoning in terms of "random variable following a distribution" and not "random variable **is equal** to an expression).
3. What does "shorter vectors are recycled" mean ? I didn't fully understand.

Source https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/cls-sum-into-a-chi-2-when-we-have-a-sum-of-chi-2.1006785/

Comment: Check the size of `y3_1[,i]` `y2_1[,i]`, `replicate(nSample_mc, rchisq(nSample_var,df=sum(2*y1+1)))` and `y2_1[,i] * replicate(nSample_mc, rchisq(nSample_var,df=sum(2*y1+1)))`.

Comment: The error does not come from the `replicate` function but from the multiplication of a vector with length 36 (y2_sp[,1]) by a vector of length 1000 (the result of `rchisq(nSample_var,df=sum(2*y1+1))`. Shorter vectors are recycled only if the length of the longer object is a multiple of the length of the shorter one (the error says just that).

Comment: @Claudio What would you suggest me please as a workaround in my case ?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure to understand what you are trying to obtain. If I read your code correctly, `y1` and `y2_sp[,1]` are all 0's, so the result of the multiplication that throws an error would be a vector of 0's anyway. Can you post the first lines of the matrix you wish to get (e.g. `y3_1` and `y3_2`? My hunch is that you would be better off by creating a dataframe instead of looping through matrices.

Comment: @Claudio . Could you take a look please at my **UPDATE**, you should understand better. Best regards

Comment: Er... no. You need to separate the *statistical* problem (for which there is a dedicated SE site) from the *coding* problem. The coding problem seems to boil down to the necessity of multiplying a vector of length 1000 by a vector of weights of length 36: that is not possible, because when the vectors are of different length R recycles the shorter one, so the result of `1:2 * 1:4` is `# 1 4 3 8`. But that works only if the longer vector has length multiple of the shorter: `1:2 * 1:5` is not possible. So you need either 1000 weights, or just 1.